# Trouble configuring search field to pass searched value into function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails, forms lately have been giving me all kinds of trouble so your help and support here would be very valuable.

In my `home.html.erb` file I have this code:

```
    <%= form_tag({:controller => "pages", :action => "search"}, :method => "get", :class => "grabTweets") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:tweets)%>   
    <% end %>
```

I'm trying to take the value that the user enters into that search field and pass it into a function called `grabTweets` that contains the following code:

```
  def grabTweets(mySearch)
    @tweet = Twitter.search(mySearch + "[pic] "+" instagr.am/i/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
    @tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
    urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings
    end
  end
```

The my form code in `home.html.erb` renders correctly but doesn't communicate with the grabTweets function. As much Googling and tinkering as I do, I can't seem to figure out the answer. The code in home.html.erb adds this to the end of my localhost URL: `/assets?utf8=✓&tweets=google`, so the search isn't being routed correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added an entry for your search action to routes.rb ? What does your search action look like ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I haven't done anything to edit my routes.rb file other than root "/" to `pages#home`. What would you suggest I do here?

Comment: @FrederickCheung How would I ask the route to call a specific function in my pages controller?

Comment: @ZackShapiro read up on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: routes are wrong in this case. Search arguments should be passed in as parameters, not inside the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things: first you need to make sure that your url gets routed to the write controller

```
match '/search', :to "pages#search"
```

ought to do it.

Then in your PagesController's search action, call

```
grabTweets(params[:tweets])
```

and do something interesting with the results. Obviously if `grabTweets` isn't an instance method on your controller then you'd need to adjust how you're calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is fine. For search, you should have the arguments passed in as GET params (as you currently are doing)

The problem is just how you're accessing the search argument. Instead of trying to read an argument in the function like this:

```
def grabTweets(mySearch)
  @tweet = Twitter.search(mySearch + "[pic] "+" instagr.am/i/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
  @tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
  urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings
  end
end
```

Read off the params hash:

```
def grabTweets
  @tweet = Twitter.search(params[:tweets] + "[pic] "+" instagr.am/i/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
  @tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
  urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings
  end
end
```

And this is Ruby. Please don't CamelCase variables.